# Alternative to Test Run for manual testing?

Tags: manual-testing

In the past, at companies that didn't yet have a robust automated testing suite, I've used [Test Run](http://www.runtestrun.com) to manage manual test scripts for multiple users. It was a pretty handy tool, but the site now seems to be defunct - upgrading past the free trial is broken and nobody seems to be answering support questions. Before I go back to copy and paste with a spreadsheet, I thought I'd check to see if anybody here knows of a similar web-based tool that is actually maintained.

It doesn't necessarily have to have every [feature](http://runtestrun.com/features.php) that Test Run did, but the ability to write test scripts, assign them to different users, and create one-off test plans from existing tests are pretty key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a LONG listing at the [Ministry of Testing](http://www.ministryoftesting.com/resources/software-testing-tools/) including a number of free tools like TestLink (Look for "Test Management" about 1/3 of the way down the page). Another list (conveniently divided into free and commercial tools, but not as extensive) can be found at [QTPBook](http://qtpbook.com/2013/04/22/best-software-testing-tools/).

I've used TestLink and it works well once configured although the user interface isn't always super-intuitive.

(Disclaimer - I have no affiliation with either of these sites. I just find the listings useful)

Comment: Thanks - this is just the kind of list I was looking for.

Comment: I hope you can find something that meets your need and budget there.

Answer (score 3):

There's an open source tool called [TestLink](http://testlink.org) you may wish to consider. (Follow the download link for their Sourceforge project).

There is an old copy of the manual [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TestLinkOpenSourceTRMS/testlink-code/testlink_1_9/docs/testlink_user_manual.pdf) that is convenient for viewing all their features quickly. It includes test cases, keywords, test plans, suites, user administration and roles.

Answer (score 2):

One of the developers behind TestRail here. You might want to check out [TestRail](http://www.gurock.com/testrail/), our web-based test management tool. TestRail is available both as a SaaS and download edition and is used by many teams.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider [ontestpad.com](https://ontestpad.com). I haven't used it beyond a trial, however it should be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a modern test case management tool that I have been involved with creating - [TestLodge](http://www.testlodge.com).

TestLodge has been completely designed based on user feedback and focuses on being productive, easy-to-use and will allow you to easily manage test cases and execute runs.

TestLodge includes a free trial.